# JDBC соединение отваливается через 30мин

Tags: jdbc, mysqlconnector

Сайт на java. Соединение с базой JDBC. После получасового не обращения к нему пропадает соединения с базой.
Добавление пула ситуацию не исправило. 
`jdbc:mysql://server:3306/mydata?autoReconnect=true`
реконнект происходит, но для этого нужно его еще раз пнуть(обновить страницу в браузере).
В какую сторону хоть копать подскажите, плиз?

Comment: Я так догадываюсь, что на стороне базы надо настраивать.

Answer (score 0):

Значение обычно контролируется DB. У вас нет контроля над ним с помощью кода. Это зависит от используемого сервера БД. Обычно это около 30 минут до одного часа.

С другой стороны, поддерживать связь навсегда - это очень плохая идея. Лучшей практикой является получение и закрытие Connection, Statement и ResultSet в кратчайшие возможные области видимости, чтобы избежать утечек ресурсов и возможных сбоев приложений, вызванных утечками и таймаутами.

Нужно не использовать одно и то же подключение, а брать каждый раз новое из пула при выполнение запроса.

Comment: resultSet.close(); и preparedStatement.close(); закрываю в DAO после каждого запроса. Но вопрос в том, как восстановить коннекшн без надобности стучатся к нему 2 раза.

Comment: я использую прямые запросы в базу без hibernate  и jpa

Comment: @Naum если соединение закрыто, то его нужно создать новое, при чем тут восстановить?

Comment: каждые 30 мин создавать и закрывать все соединения описанные в DAO? Мне кажется должно быть решение попроще.

Comment: @Naum после выполнения любой транзакции

Comment: Как раз для быстрого использования кол-во подключения и нужен пул соединений

Comment: так проблема не в большом кол-ве, а в отсутсвии оных. если транзакций никаких не было 30 мин. то при запросе в базу происходит соединение, а  resultSet = null

Comment: @Naum Я же сказал при каждом запросе нужно создать новое подключение

Comment: @Naum обновил ответ